# modify the size of an image according to a circle so that the two images are superimposed by having the circle of each one on top of the other PYTHON

Tags: python, opencv, resize, size, target

I have two input images: one is the template and the other is the image that the user will provide. They don't necessarily have the same size. Their only common point is a circle.

This circle I want the second image to adapt to have the same dimmension. So by zooming in or out and moving the circle so that the two images are superimposed with the circle which is well aligned.

I tried a lot of things to resize the circles to the same size and to align them but I didn't succeed in anything.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Charger les images
before_image = cv2.imread("before.jpg")
after_image = cv2.imread("center_after_2.jpg")
gray_before = cv2.cvtColor(before_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_after = cv2.cvtColor(after_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Appliquer une réduction de bruit pour faciliter la détection de cercles
gray_before = cv2.medianBlur(gray_before, 5)
gray_after = cv2.medianBlur(gray_after, 5)

# Détecter les cercles dans les images
circles_before = cv2.HoughCircles(gray_before, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=150, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
circles_after = cv2.HoughCircles(gray_after, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 30, param1=150, param2=150, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)



# Extraire les coordonnées x, y, et rayon du cercle dans les images
x1, y1, r1 = int(circles_before[0, 0, 0]), int(circles_before[0, 0, 1]), int(circles_before[0, 0, 2])
x2, y2, r2 = int(circles_after[0, 0, 0]), int(circles_after[0, 0, 1]), int(circles_after[0, 0, 2])

before_image = cv2.cvtColor(before_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.circle(before_image, (x1, y1), r1, (255,0,0), 2)
before_image = cv2.cvtColor(before_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.circle(after_image, (x2, y2), r2, (255,0,0), 2)

plt.imshow(before_image)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(after_image)
plt.show()
```

**before_image and after_image**

[image: before_image and after_image]

**before_image**

[image: before_image]

**center_after_2**

[image: center_after_2]

Comment: Please share what you have done so far regarding resizing. You already have the radiuses of the circles, it should not be that hard to scale one image, so that the radiuses of both circles is the same. We need to know what exactly your problem is

Comment: I managed to make the radius of the two circles the same. The problem is to position them one above the other to the nearest pixel. I couldn't get it right.

Comment: So how did you scale the images, so that the radiuses match? I cannot find that in your code. Placing the center points (you already have the coordinates) 'on top of each other' is simply a matter of translation. Either using `wrapAffine` (which you might already use for scaling ?) or by using python list-slice operations

Comment: I immediately reverted the code that allowed me to put the circles at the same level because the result did not suit me. So I can't show you but even with the coordinates I didn't succeed. Do you have a small example code, to maybe show me how to do it?

Comment: Translation and scaling can both be implemented (at the same time) as an affine transformation. Documentation with example can be found here https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d4/d61/tutorial_warp_affine.html as pointed out, there are other ways to implement

Comment: Maybe you could attach the pictures you have used, so that others can reproduce